# Checked Out To column not viewable

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, list-view, modern-experience

I am trying to add the Checked Out To column to my SharePoint library.

I can see the column in the Library Settings here:

[image: librarysettiings]

But when I go to add the column in the library, it doesn't show up:

[image: addcolumn]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see the same behavior in modern experience of SharePoint library. So in this case, you can show the column in library view using old/classic experience way.

Follow below steps to add "Checked Out To" column to library view:

1. Go to Library settings
2. Scroll down to the **Views** section
3. Click on the view name where you want to add "Checked Out To" column (For example: **All Documents**)

[image]

4. On list view settings page, Select the checkbox against "Checked Out To" column in columns list
5. Click **OK**.

   [image]